# Extending the matrix property to nilpotent operators in infinite dimensional spaces.

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, nilpotence

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be nilpotent matrix such that $A^{4} = 0$, We can find matrix $B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that we have $$AB \neq 0 \ \ and \ \ BA = 0$$
The question is as follows:

How can we extend this property to the infinite dimensionl?
if A is nilpotent operators such that $A^{4} = 0$ in infinite dimentional banach space.

Comment: The first property can be proven using Jordan's form

Comment: you have to suppose at least $A\ne 0$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ is an operator over a vector space $V$ such that $A^k =0$ for some finite $k > 1$ and that $A^{k-1} \neq 0$. There must exist a vector $v \in V$ such that $A^{k-1} v \neq 0$. Moreover, there exists a linear functional $f:V \to \Bbb F$ such that $f(A^{k-1} v) \neq 0$.

Define $B$ to be the operator
$$
B(x) = f(A^{k-1}x)v.
$$
Verify that $B \circ A = 0$. On the other hand, $A \circ B$ cannot be zero because
$$
A(Bv) = A(f(A^{k-1}v)v) = f(A^{k-1}v)Av \neq 0.
$$

Comment: Why did you write $
A(Bv) = f(A^{k-1}v)v \neq 0.
$ instead of $
A(Bv) =ََA( f(A^{k-1}v)v) \neq 0.
$ and thanks

Comment: @Hicham That is because I made a mistake :) your version is correct; see my latest edit